# How to set up the sendmail configration from script?

Tags: php, email, sendmail

Is there a way in which we can just configure the sendmail settings dynamically from PHP script, instead of going manually to php.ini and sendmail.ini files to make changes?

Can we do this by using an HTML form allowing a user to change the values?

Comment: You can use ini_set (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) to change php.ini config values from a script. But it might not be a good idea to let the user change configuration files values from a HTML form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something such as PHPMailer instead: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Example usage:

```
require('./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = 'This is the message content';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'sender@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = '12345';

$mail->SetFrom('sender@gmail.com', $name);
$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@mycompany.com','no-reply');
$mail->Subject    = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('abc1@gmail.com', 'title1');
$mail->AddAddress('abc2@gmail.com', 'title2'); /* ... */

$mail->AddAttachment($fileName);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: can you help how i can speed up the mail take 10 seconds to send a mail can i lower the amount of time it takes ?